# Source file ‘c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/emacs-26.1-x86_64/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/progmodes/python.el’ newer than byte-compiled file

Tags: byte-compilation

this message shows up on Emacs startup. what does it mean and how to get rid of it?

`Source file ‘c:/Users/jcao/AppData/Local/emacs-26.1-x86_64/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/progmodes/python.el’ newer than byte-compiled file`

btw, my setting folder is `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d` and I recently made some changes there.

Answer (score 1):

In general, such a message appears when a user modifies a Lisp file after it has been byte-compiled.  There might be as many as three types of files relating to the same library; e.g., `python.el.gz` (compressed archive), `python.el` (flat text file) and `python.elc` (byte-compiled file).  Perhaps a user visits a library to look at how a function or variable is defined (e.g., with `find-library`, `find-function`, `find-variable`, `find-face`, etc.) and inadvertently modifies and saves the file.

If the modifications to the library are desired, then go ahead and re-byte-compile the file with `M-x byte-compile-file` and type in the absolute path to the file.  Another way to accomplish this is to visit the directory in `dired-mode`, place the cursor on the file to be byte-compiled, and press the capital letter "B" which is bound to `dired-do-byte-compile`.

If the modifications to the library are *not* desired, then restore the original *.el file by extracting a new one from the zipped archive, or obtaining the original from the source files used to build the executable.  If the *.el file is newer than the *.elc file, then re-byte-compile as indicated above.

There are other likely reasons such a inadvertently touching the file with something like the `touch` command ... if no revisions to the file, then just re-byte-compile as indicated above.

Comment: Thanks @lawlist for your help!